# NodeJS warning: possible event emitter leak. 11 open listeners added

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, node-modules

I'm using NodeJS and WS to test out websockets. To offload some work from the server, I want to send pings from the client to the server instead of the other way around. However, whenever i run my code i get this error:

```
> (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 pong listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at WebSocket.addListener (events.js:239:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/NodeJS-Runtime/websockets/client.js:40:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

here is my code:

```
for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
    const clientNum = i;
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080', {
    perMessageDeflate: false
        });

    ws.onerror = function(error) {
        if(!hasFailed && clientNum != 0)
            console.log('failed on: ' + clientNum + error);
        hasFailed = true;
    }

    ws.on('open', function() {
        // Send keep alive messages. Close if no response.
        ws.keepAlive = false;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (ws.keepAlive) {
                ws.close();
            } else {
                ws.ping(null, null, true);
                ws.keepAlive = true;
            }
        }, 25*1000); // milliseconds between pings

    });
    ws.on("pong", function() { 
            ws.keepAlive = false; 
    });
```

I get this error for both the pong and 'on' function.

Comment: I just tested a rewrite of this code using `ws@3.0.0` and node v 7.5.0, and I get no warnings, even with 100 clients per cluster. [Here's my attached code in a zip file for reference](https://puu.sh/vUIt9/61c065e185.zip). I apologize but I couldn't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error, that's a warning. If you want to disable the warning, call [`ws.setMaxListeners(0)`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n) to indicate you know you're setting more than 10 listeners, so that the runtime can see you know what you're doing.

In addition, setting the `ws.onerror` attribute is bad practice. Instead, you'll want to call `ws.on('error', function (error) {...`, but that is not related to the problem you're asking about.

Comment: I understand, sorry for the mistaken terminology. What i'm more worried about is if i have a bug that is causing that error. People say it only happens if you have 11 emitters on the same object. But i only want 2 emitters per object.

Comment: @dalanb it's possible that the `ws` module is already assigning 10 other listeners internally in order to support the attribute-assignment listener callbacks that you were using for `onerror`, for example. I cannot confirm this, though, but I assume that is the case. In any case, if you're worried about memory leaks, you can assign a value of `12` and test it with that.

Comment: well the error goes away if I make the for loop less than 10 or change ws from const to var.

Comment: However, if it is a var, it doesn't work properly with ping/pong and events arent captured

Comment: In that case, you're going to need to provide more code. Specifically, how are you importing `WebSocket`. I feel that might be related to the issue.

Comment: const WebSocket = require('ws');

Comment: Oh, I just noticed another thing. You use `i` in the error callback. In the `for` loop, it should be declared with `let`, otherwise the `i` in the callback will always be equal to `10`. But as to your main issue, I can't really see the root of the problem yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144614/discussion-between-patrick-roberts-and-dalanb).